# Laravel Mongodb groupby

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Am trying to pick the last record from the MongoDB using Laravel MongoDB package. I have a many transaction ID in the database in which some are duplicate ID due to some reasons. In that scenario, I need to `groupby` the transaction id, and sort it according to time and get the last one.

example

```
transcation_id status timestamps
1              success 
2              success
3              failed
4              success
3              failed
5              success
3              success
```

So when I am querying I need the `transaction_id` of `3` as `success`, which is the last status with the time stamp. However, my query gives me `3` as `failed`.

```
$query  = MyCollection::whereIn('app_id' , $appId->toArray())
                ->select(['transcation_id',.....,'created_at'])
                ->orderBy('updated_at')
                ->groupBy('transcation_id')
                ->get();
```

Please correct me where am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel collections has method last

```
Model::all() -> last(); // last element
```

This is the best way to do it.

For better solutions use this  [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-last)

Comment: Does jessenger Laravel MongoDB package supports the `last` method?

Comment: @ArunCode Yes supports to jessenger also

Comment: Tried, the method does not seem to work. `Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::last()`